# Java multiply value from a List and Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a code that will output the data from a List and Map. How do I multiply the corresponding number with each other?

The output from List

```
{prepare=0.25, saturday=0.5, republic=0.25, approach=0.25, ...}
```

The output from Map

```
[0, 1, 0, 0,...]
```

I need to make them multiply with corresponding number and sum them up. The **total will be my desired output** like this:

```
(0.25*0)+(0.5*1)+(0.25*0)+(0.25*0).... = total
```

This is my example code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class WordOcc {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String someText = "hurricane gilbert head dominican coast saturday. hurricane gilbert sweep dominican republic sunday civil  prepare high wind heavy rain high sea. storm approach southeast sustain wind  mph   mph. there alarm civil defense director   a television alert shortly midnight saturday.";

    List<List<String>> sort = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> res = new HashMap<>();

    for (String sentence : someText.split("[.?!]\\s*"))
    {
        sort.add(Arrays.asList(sentence.split("[ ,;:]+"))); //put each sentences in list
    }

    // put all word in a hashmap with 0 count initialized
    int sentenceCount = sort.size();

    for (List<String> sentence: sort) {
        sentence.stream().forEach(x -> res.put(x, new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(sentenceCount, 0))));
    }

    int index = 0;
    // count the occurrences of each word for each sentence.
    for (List<String> sentence: sort) {
        for (String q : sentence) {
            res.get(q).set(index, res.get(q).get(index) + 1); 
        }
        index++;
    }


    Map<String,Float>word0List = getFrequency(res);

    System.out.println(word0List + "\n"); //print the list value      

    //get first sentence count value from each word
    List<Integer> sentence0List = getSentence(0, res);

    System.out.println(sentence0List + "\n"); //print the map value
  }

  static List<Integer> getSentence(int sentence, Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map) {
      return map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getValue().get(sentence)).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

 static Map<String, Float> getFrequency(Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> stringMap) {
  Map<String, Float> res = new HashMap<>();
 stringMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> res.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() / (float)e.getValue().size()));
        return res;
      }

}
```

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: This is unclear. Could you explain what the current code is doing, what it is supposed to be doing and what it is doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the current code. I'm just unsure on how to multiply the the value between List and Map. The current output from list and map is as stated and I need to multiply them with each other corresponding to their position.

Comment: Note: a HashMap has no inherent order nor should you expect one.

Comment: What if the same word appears more than once in a sentence?

Comment: The List will only store one instance of the word. You may try it here: https://repl.it/Bg6D/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what your are looking for since there is no order to expect from a hashmap as mentioned in the comments. But as you have described you want to do something like this:

```
float result = 0;
Float[] hmValues = word0List.values().toArray(new Float[0]);
for(int i = 0; i < word0List.size(); i++)
    result += hmValues[i] * sentence0List.get(i);
```

Comment: One thing to note. It's a good practice to always have braces around blocks of code. Including one-liner "if" statments, or "for" loops.